# get the route according to to the current time

Tags: mysql, sql, openshift

I am testing table on the locanhost and `Openshift` I am facing the problem that on openshift I am not getting anything back (no error. the query is being executed successfully  but no result)although on the localhost I am getting the route `9` back. On openshift I am insert arrivaltime according to the server time. On localhost I am inserting arrivaltime according to my local host. Please can anyone explain me the reason for this behavior?

I appreciate any help.

```
CREATE TABLE test(
id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 arrivaltime Time  NOT NULL,
 route INT(11) NOT NULL   
)

INSERT INTO test(arrivaltime, route) values('14:23:00', 9)

SELECT route FROM test
WHERE arrivaltime BETWEEN curtime() - INTERVAL 2 MINUTE AND curtime() + INTERVAL 2 MINUTE
```

Openshift time:

```
   SELECT  curtime()
    14:22:45
```

The result on Openshift:

[image]

Comment: So what is your problem? your `curtime() = 14:22:45` and tyour data stored is `'14:14:00'` so your condition is `FALSE`  and mysql return empty record set. What is your expectation?

Comment: @alex no that was just an instance to see how the time system on openshift is i corrected it to avoid confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is fine. The problem is just data inserted.

You can play with my fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba15c/1

Just add another line into `INSERT` statemnet and rebuild schema, and press **Run SQL** button. everything is ok. I am sure, that problem is just real value inserted in database.

Comment: I know that my query is fine because I am getting a result on the localhost but on openshift see my screenshot. Could it be a bug of openshift?